# How can I re render the FlatList conditionally depending on a global state variable

Tags: redux, react-native-flatlist, rerender

In a parent screen I am using useFocusEffect to reload the data every time I come back from a child screen and the parent screen gets focus. But I want to achieve this conditionally depending on a redux flag state (casosFlag) which I set to true in a child screen. I am trying to do it the following way:

```
// Get the casosFlag value to know if the casos FlatList has to be refreshed
    
const casosFlag = useSelector((state) => state.global.casosFlag);
     
useFocusEffect(
   useCallback(() => {               
      obtenerCasos();        
},[casosFlag]));
```

But I noticed that obtenerCasos() (load data function) runs before useSelector, then it never gets executed. And if I take off the useCallback dependency [casosFlag], obtenerCasos() runs every time the parent screen gets focus (unconditionally), which I don't want to happen.

This the my FlashList which I want to be refreshed conditionally every time I come back, from child to parent, with the global state variable containing a true value. Notice that I am using extraData={setFilteredDataSource} to tell the FlashList that has to re render, which is working perfectly.

```
<FlashList
   keyboardShouldPersistTaps={"handled"}
   data={filteredDataSource}
   initialNumToRender={5}
   renderItem={renderItem}
   keyExtractor={(item) =\> item.CaseId}
   estimatedItemSize={250}
   extraData={setFilteredDataSource}
\>
```

I am new in react native, I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how can I re render the FlashList depending on the value of my redux global state casosFlag, when its value is true. Or, if there is another better practice to get the same result. Thanks in advance. Daniel.